# How do I disable the "(formerly known as X)" message when I join a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I joined a friend's server I got a message that looked like this:

> Player (formerly known as Player1) joined the game.

Those aren't the real names, but is there any way to stop this? I don't really want people to know my old username.

Comment: This looks like it might be something server-side, in which case there is really nothing you can do other than talk to your friend about it (assuming he's the one running the server) or talking to whomever runs the server.

Comment: @Yuuki But are there any settings to disable it?

Comment: I am not sure, it depends on what the server is doing to achieve this. In all likelihood, there is a way to disable it, though I can't be sure on whether it can be disabled on an individual basis.

Comment: @Yuuki this is plain vanilla and happens when you changed your name via minecraft.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is supposed to show exactly once for every server you have played on with your old username. See this [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2uu840/formerly_known_as_derped_mai_pants_how_long_will/) by a Mojang Support person:

> Once per server that you previously logged into with your old name.

I said supposed up there because there has been a bug that caused the message to show up every time you log in, which was fixed in [1.8.4](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.8.4) according to the wiki.

> **Fixes**
>
> - [...]
> - [MC-78020](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-78020) – "User (formerly known as olduser) has joined" shows multiple times

Ask your friend to upgrade the server to version 1.8.6. This version is fully compatible with previous 1.8 releases.

Comment: I can't update because I'm using mods. However, I did not realize that it should only show up once, because it has happened at least 5 times.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you changed your username. I don't think there is a way to disable it without Bukkit/Spigot plugins.

Comment: Bukkit is down for now its realitivly hard to get those files and the majority of the staff left

Comment: @Will309 You can still build the latest version of Bukkit yourself using the Spigot Buildtools jar, but I'd use Spigot anyways as it is just an improved version of Bukkit.